# How to convert non linear constraint to new linear constraints?

Tags: network-programming, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I have converted the non-linear expression [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzzSO.png into linear equations 11, 12 and 13. But when I run my code, I got these errors: "constraint labeling not supported for dimensions with variable size, use named constraints instead", "CPLEX cannot extract expression", "Element "cons12" not defined" and "Invalid initialization expression for element "cons12" ". Can you help me, what should I do? Thanks in advance.

```
using CPLEX;

//Total nodes number. 
range Nodes = 1..9;
//{int} Nodes = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
//................................................................................

//Total links number

//two_directed
tuple edge{
  int node_out;
  int node_in;
          };
 {edge} L with node_out, node_in in Nodes = {<1,3>, <3,1>, <2,3>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <4,3>, <3,5>, 
                                             <5,3>, <3,6>, <6,3>, <4,5>, <5,4>, <4,6>, <6,4>, 
                                             <4,8>, <8,4>, <5,6>, <6,5>, <6,7>, <7,6>, <6,9>, 
                                             <9,6>};
  {edge} Lout[Nodes] = [{<1,3>},//node1
                 {<2,3>},//node2
                 {<3,1>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <3,5>, <3,6>},//node3
                 {<4,3>, <4,5>, <4,6>, <4,8>},//node4
                 {<5,3>, <5,4>, <5,6>},//node5
                 {<6,3>, <6,4>, <6,5>, <6,7>, <6,9>},//node6
                 {<7,6>},//node7
                 {<8,4>},//node8
                 {<9,6>}];//node9 
 //Flows
 tuple cflow{
   int origin;
   int destination;
           }
 {cflow} F with origin,destination in Nodes = {<1,2>, <1,3>, <1,4>, <1,5>, <1,6>, <1,7>, 
                      <1,8>, <1,9>, <2,1>, <2,3>, <2,4>, <2,5>, <2,6>, <2,7>, <2,8>, <2,9>, 
                      <3,1>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <3,5>, <3,6>, <3,7>, <3,8>, <3,9>, 
                      <4,1>, <4,2>, <4,3>, <4,5>, <4,6>, <4,7>, <4,8>, <4,9>, 
                      <5,1>, <5,2>, <5,3>, <5,4>, <5,6>, <5,7>, <5,8>, <5,9>,
                      <6,1>, <6,2>, <6,3>, <6,4>, <6,5>, <6,7>, <6,8>, <6,9>, <7,1>, <7,2>};
 
float landa_f[f in F]=[0.86, 0.3, 0.75, 0.23, 0.32, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.22, 0.14, 
                       0.23, 0.42, 0.33, 0.5, 0.62, 0.36, 0.42, 0.35, 0.2, 0.16,
                       0.33, 0.9, 0.41, 0.51, 0.61, 0.33, 0.42, 0.51, 0.87, 0.96,
                       0.31, 0.55, 0.91, 0.36, 0.32, 0.72, 0.76, 0.32, 0.45, 0.64,
                       0.38, 0.71, 0.43, 0.55, 0.53, 0.9, 0.58, 0.97, 0.5, 0.33 ];
 
   {string} V = {"IDS", "DPI", "NAT", "Proxy", "Firewall"};
 
  //MAIN DECISION VARIABLES
  dvar int I[v in V][n in Nodes][f in F][j in 1..2] in 0..1; //denotes that an NF instance v 
  hosted at node n is used by the j-th service on the service chain of flow f.

  dvar int IL[l in L][f in F][j in 1..2][n in Nodes] in 0..1;//denotes that link l is used by 
  flow f to route from the j-th to (j + 1)-th NF service, hosted at node nj and nj+1.

  dvar int Y[v in V][n in Nodes];

  //Decision variables related  with non linear equations
  dvar int z[l in L][f in F][j in 1..2][n in Nodes][v in V] in 0..1;

subject to{
     //convert non_linear_equations to new linear constraints
     forall (f in F, j in 1..2, v in V) 
     cons11: sum( l in Lout[item(Routes[f],j-1)] ) z[l][f][j][item(Routes[f],j-1)][v] == 1;
                        
   forall (f in F, j in 1..2, l in Lout[item(Routes[f],j-1)], v in V) {
    
    cons12: 3 * z[l][f][j][item(Routes[f],j-1)][v] <= ( IL[l][f][j][item(Routes[f],j-1)] + 
                 I[v][item(Routes[f],j-1)][f][j] );     
    cons13:   z[l][f][j][item(Routes[f],j-1)][v] >= ( IL[l][f][j][item(Routes[f],j-1)] + 
                 I[v][item(Routes[f],j-1)][f][j] ) - 2;  }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed

```
dvar int x[1..2][1..2];

{int} s[1..2]=[{1,2},{1}];

subject to
{
  forall(i in 1..2) forall(j in s[i]) ct:x[i][j]<=0;
}       

execute
{
  writeln(ct[1][1].UB);
}
```

does not work but if you write

```
dvar float x[1..2][1..2];



{int} s[1..2]=[{1,2},{1}];

subject to
{
  forall(i in 1..2) forall(j in 1..2:j in s[i]) ct:x[i][j]<=0;
}   

execute
{
  writeln(ct[1][1].UB);
}
```

then it works fine

```
 range r=1..2;

dvar float x[1..2][1..2];

constraint ct[r][r];

{int} s[1..2]=[{1,2},{1}];

subject to
{
  forall(i in 1..2,j in 1..2)  
  ct[i][j]= if (j in s[i]) x[1][i]<=0;
}   

execute
{
  writeln(ct[1][1].UB);
}
```

works fine too

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Fleischer. I worked your guide but my problem didn't solve. I think my problem is about l in Lout[item(Routes[f],j-1) , l in L  in dec. if you have time, can you help me more?

Comment: Hi, I helped you with the error "constraint labeling not supported for dimensions with variable size, use named constraints instead". I encourage you to start new questions for other errors with .mod AND .dat so that other users can help you